# Sikuli javascript is not available

Tags: sikuli

I've Sikuli IDE and want to use Javascript for scripting, but option for it is not available:

[image]

But according to [docs](https://sikulix-2014.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it is supported. How can I enable javascript?

My Java version is 1.8.0_401.